# Swift 4 Codable get first array from array

Tags: swift, codable

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  success: true,
  message: null,
  messages: null,
  data: [
    [ ... ]
  ]
}
```

Now I am wondering, I can solve this with:

```
struct Something: Codable {
    let data: [[Data]]
}

something.data.flatMap { $0 }
```

But I would rather do:

```
struct Something: Codable {
    let data: [Data]
}
```

I already know I can achieve navigation through JSON with sets of `CodingKeys` enums and `container.nestedContainer(...)` but how do I achieve this when there's no key, but just an array in an array? Can I achieve this with the custom init on `Decodable` and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to write a custom initializer for flattening the array

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let success : Bool
    let data : [Foo]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case success, data }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        let arrayData = try container.decode([[Foo]].self, forKey: .data)
        guard !arrayData.isEmpty else {  throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .data, in: container, debugDescription: "Object is empty")  }
        data = arrayData.first!
    }

}

struct Foo : Decodable { ... }
```

The type `Data` exists in the Foundation framework. You are strongly discouraged from using it as custom type.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right about your remark, it was just a PoC kind of code, not real code fortunately. But thank you so much, I'm going with `data = arrayData.flatMap { $0 }` for now.